# Are the unary operators tree-nodes in the AST?

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

So I am trying to build and AST for boolean expression. Basically the expression is composed of boolean operands separated by AND, OR, NOT and paranthesis. Ex:

```
(true AND false) AND NOT(NOT true)

false AND NOT TRUE OR true
```

I am working in C# and I have classes for the TreeNode which holds the operands of an expression (LHS, RHS) and the the operator and I also have classes for the leafs of the tree that hold the boolean values.

What I am not sure how to represent is the unary NOT operator... Should I use the TreeNode class and use just on of the branches? Should I create a 'Link' class that links two expressions via an unary operator edge?

Answer (score 2):

I see three possibilities:

- What you supposed with an NOT node that has only one child (if you don't mind that your tree won't be binary)
- Give each node a property indicating if it is negated or not
- Or the electronics way of using NAND and one child being True.

Comment: The third case could arguably be any operator that computes "NOT" (NOR, XOR, ...).  But as a practical rule nobody ever uses that or the second case. The point of an AST is abstract away detail (NAND with True is clearly extra [useless] detail) and unneeded complexity, as is a flag on the node (would you do that for the negate operator too?).  Better to let that AST nodes have different numbers of children, so that they can represent thier exact set of operands well.   This suggest that a pure binary tree is bad choice too, as you can't represent a ternary operator such as C's  x?y:z.

Comment: ... of course, you can always represent an N-ary tree with a binary one (essentially you encode an N-ary operator as a node with the first operand, whose second operand is effectively an N-1-ary operator corresponding to "the rest of N-ary operation" [a curried operator]).  But that IMHO is alway a somewhat clumsy representation and not very abstract.